# Is iterator being invalidated?

Tags: c++, iterator

Is iterator invalidated after:

```
string b "Some string";
auto beg_ = b.begin();
auto end_ = b.end();
b.erase(beg_);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but erase return a valid iterator you can use to continue in a loop :

> For the remaining members, the
>   function returns an iterator of member
>   type string::iterator referring to the
>   character that now occupies the
>   position of the first character
>   erased, or, if no such character
>   exists, returns end().

Source : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Standard says

> References, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of a `basic_string` sequence may be invalidated
>   by the following uses of that `basic_string` object:
>
> - Calling non-const member functions, except `operator[]()`, `at()`, `begin()`, `rbegin()`, `end()`, and `rend()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html

> Iterators may be invalidated by swap,
>   reserve, insert, and erase (and by
>   functions that are equivalent to
>   insert and/or erase, such as clear,
>   resize, append, and replace).
>   Additionally, however, the first call
>   to any non-const member function,
>   including the non-const version of
>   begin() or operator[], may invalidate
>   iterators.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, yes.
Erase and insert operations invalidate iterators.

But erase(iterator) also returns an iterator you may be able to use.